Attach VS Code terminal to R script when working interactively with HPC/Slurm
I'm connecting via VS Code web to an HPC cluster. I'm then using salloc to request resources and can then use either srun or ssh to start an interactive session, as described in this SO response.
However, when I do this, I lose VS Code's R integration and have to copy-paste code from my R script into the terminal to execute it in the interactive session.
Is there any way I can attach the interactive session to my R script, such that I can use keyboard shortcuts (e.g. ctrl+enter) and ideally get full integration with the R extension in VS Code?

You can add this to your settings.json. That will send the code to the active terminal (but you won't have full integration)

"r.alwaysUseActiveTerminal": true

